# How do I remove the space between character and a letter?

Tags: python, pandas

[image]

How do I remove space between ' and a letter?

Comment: You and use `strip()` to remove unnecessary space.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
lst = ["' Deep learning'", "' Games'"]


out = [f"'{i[1:-1].strip()}'" for i in lst]
print(out)

# Output
["'Deep learning'", "'Games'"]
```